# HIVE where date filter by x days back? string format

Tags: string, hive, where-clause

so our DBA's setup our hive table with the date column as the partition column, but as a "string" YYYYMMDD format.

How can I WHERE filter this "date" column for something like last 30 days?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `date_format` to format systemdate - 30 days into YYYYMMDD and then compare with your partition column. Please note to use partition column as is so hive can choose correct partitions.
When you want to pick previous 30th days data -

```
select * 
from  mytable 
where partition_col = date_format( current_date() - interval '30' days, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

If you want all data since last 30 days -

```
select * 
from  mytable 
wherecast(partition_col as INT) >= cast(date_format( current_date() - interval '30' days, 'yyyyMMdd') as INT)
```

casting shouldnt impact partition benefits but you need to check the performance before using it. Please get back in such scenario.

Comment: thank you. So no need to fiddle with unix time conversions?

Comment: nope. you are using it in another option so no.